# How to add a constant text to all headings in Office Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, find-and-replace

In an effort to manually change my Office Word document to Latex, I would like to change all text with `Heading` style with a text containing the `\section{heading}`, in which `heading` is the actual text of each heading.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Microsoft Word document and determine what the *Style* is that you want replaced with text.

   - NOTE: In these steps, the following examples will be used however they can be adjusted as needed:

     - *Style* is: **Heading 2**
     - The *text* that will replace the existing text is: **Replacement text**.
2. Create a copy of the document to ensure that no information is inadvertently lost.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.
4. Click the **More >>** button and place your cursor in the **Find what:** field.
5. Under the *Replace* heading, click **Format** and select **Style**.
6. From the *Find Style* list, select the corresponding style (for example, **Heading 2**) and click **OK**.
7. Leave the **Find what** field empty and place your cursor in the **Replace with** field.

   - This will replace the whole *heading* with the text that you enter in step 9. If you only want a certain phrase/character/word to be found, use the various search operators that come with Microsoft Word. —See [Using wildcards](http://www.officetooltips.com/word/tips/using_wildcards.html).
8. (*Optional*) If you want the replaced text to have formatting, repeat steps 5-6 to select the appropriate formatting and style to be applied.
9. In the **Replace with** field, enter the text that will replace the exsting text. (For example, **Replacement text**.)
10. Click **Replace** and confirm that the action works as expected.
11. If you are confident with the Find & Replace, click **Replace All**, otherwise click **Replace** one at a time to make sure that no work is lost.
12. If needed, perform a **Compare** of the two documents afterwards.

    - This can be done by clicking the **Review** tab and selecting **Compare**. —See [Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Compare-document-differences-using-the-legal-blackline-option-dbfc7351-4022-43a2-a0c4-54d1898702a0).